# KendoWindow: adjust programmatically window height to make vertical scroll-bar disappear

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

[Given these two KendoWindows](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/kQ5Sm/24/) with the same content, where the first one has a vertical scroll-bar and the second one doesn't, is it possible to calculate/set the KendoWindows height of the first window to fit the text (and make the scroll-bar disappear)?

This is the jsfiddle javascript:

```
$("#dialog1").kendoWindow();
var dialog1 = $("#dialog1").data("kendoWindow");
dialog1.setOptions({
     width: 500,
     height: 50
});


$("#dialog2").kendoWindow();
var dialog2 = $("#dialog2").data("kendoWindow");
dialog2.setOptions({
     width: 500,
     height: 100
});

$("#dialog2").closest(".k-window").css({
    top: 200
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete height property and you'll got exacly what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/kQ5Sm/26/

```
$("#dialog1").kendoWindow();
var dialog1 = $("#dialog1").data("kendoWindow");
dialog1.setOptions({
     width: 500,
});
```